# Java, "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, cmd, компиляция

Сразу скажу, что в кодинге я абсолютный новичок, и поэтому могу тупить. Вот мой код :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AreaOfCircle{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println ("enter radius, blyat : ");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        float radius=input.nextFloat();
        float area = 3.14f*radius*radius;
        System.out.println("The area of circle with radius"+radius+"is equal to" +Math.round(area));
}}
```

Я его прописал, и когда я его закомпайлил, все было нормально, но когда я попытался его включить, он выдал мне вышеуказанную ошибку. Я не понял почему, полез в интернет, там был совет с " java . -classpath"  но даже так джава не могла найти код. Я снова полез в интернет, и понял что моих знаний не хватает, чтобы понять тамошние действия. Писал я код в Sublime Text 3, не знаю, поможет или нет

Comment: Вы хотите скомпилировать через консоль ? Если да то почитаете здесь. https://ru.wikihow.com/компилировать-и-запускать-программу-Java-с-помощью-командной-строки

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш класс `AreaOfCircle` заведен без пакета (то есть нет объявления `package`):

```
//предполагается что запускаете с каталога где лежит AreaOfCirlce.class
java -cp . AreaOfCircle
```

Если есть декларация перед классом типа `package my.package`, то надо запускать так:

```
java -cp . my.package.AreaOfCircle
```

В общем случае командная строка должна выглядеть так:

```
java -cp [folder] [full class name]
```

где:

```
[folder] - каталог где лежит дерево каталогов файлов .class
[full class name] - полное имя класса с указанием пакета
```